# Calculate number of certain days of the week between two dates

Tags: microsoft-office

I'm trying to create an Excel spreadsheet to make sure that my patients (who are seen twice per week usually) receive all the visits they are authorized by insurance for within their "auth window." Is there a formula for calculating the number of, let's say Mondays and Wednesdays or Tuesdays and Thursdays between 2 dates such as 7/4/19 and 1/4/20?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Apple hardware, software or services in the [scope defined](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: is that date.. formatted as MM/DD/YY or DD/MM/YY ?

Comment: Other optionally faster solutions : use [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=How+many+Tuesday+between+7-Apr-19+and+1-Apr-20)